# Is “춥다” an irregular adjective?

Tags: grammar, inflection

I’m learning to conjugate into past tense in formal language (합쇼체). From what I’ve learned, if a stem ends in a consonant, you add “았습니다” or “있습니다” after it depending on the vowel before.

However, I’ve seen 춥다 conjugated into 추었습니다 , dropping the ㅂ altogether.

My question is: - is 춥다 an anomaly for doing this or is there another rule during conjugation that I need to know (for when to drop ending consonants)?

Comment: A bit of spelling checks: “있습니다” → “-**었**습니다,” “추었습니다” → “추**웠**습니다.”

Comment: Just an off-topic note: 춥다 is an irregular *Korean adjective* meaning "to be cold."

Comment: @Klmo Off-topic? No, that’s pretty valid and helpful comment. But to be more precise, it means just “_cold_,” because it’s an adjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hoping someone else would explain it in detail, let me just give you a tiny bit of info about this phenomenon.

## Is “춥다” an irregular adjective?

Yes, along with other “-ㅂ” stem adjectives/verbs except for some. We can't say every such adjective/verb is, but a bunch are.

### ㅂ irregular inflection

It’s called “*ㅂ irregular inflection* (*ㅂ 불규칙 활용*).” It’s inflection where a stem’s final “ㅂ,” as in “ㅂ” in “춥-,” becomes an “ㅗ” or “ㅜ” before an inflection suffix with no initial consonant, such as “-었-.” E.g. “춥다” → “추웠다” [“추”＋(“ㅂ-”→“ㅜ-”)＋“-었-”＋“-다”].

#### Why does this happen?

Such a “ㅂ” was originally a “ㅸ” (unused nowadays), which likely had the /v/ sound at the initial position of a syllable and the /p/ sound (with [no audible release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release)) at the final. Later, the /v/ sound shifted to the /w/ sound.

> (“추ᇦ-”＋“-어”) → “추ᄫᅥ” (Since “-어” has no initial consonant, the “ㅸ” takes the initial position here.) → “추워”

---

### Fun fact: some dialects still have this sound.

The Kyungsang dialect. They say “추ᄫᅳ라 /choovɾa/” for the standard equivalent “추워라 /choowoɾa/.”

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This answers my question perfectly and in so much detail! I shall be sure to remember this phenomenon in future. :)

Comment: I think this is a perfect answer for language learners. I would just add that these verbs and adjectives have the same phenomenon: 굽다, 눕다, 덥다, 돕다, 괴롭다, 가렵다, 그립다, 아름답다, 무섭다, 아니꼽다, -스럽다.